# How to start ActiveMQ when tomcat starts?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

How do I configure my J2EE application so that I can invoke ActiveMQ service along with tomcat server? I am aware about embedded broker, here asking how to start the ActiveMQ whenever I start tomcat

Current Code (works fine) :
Now I want to remove main() method and use the code to run when tomcat runs.

```
public class JMSService {


public void produceJMS() throws NamingException, JMSException {

    ConnectionFactory connFactory =  new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);

    Connection conn = connFactory.createConnection();

    conn.start();

    Session session = conn.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQueue");

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Test Message ");

    // send the message
    producer.send(message);

    System.out.println("sent: " + message);
}}
```

Here is my consumer :

```
 public class JMSReceiver implements MessageListener,ExceptionListener {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JMSReceiver re = new JMSReceiver();
    re.receiveJMS();    
  }

 public void receiveJMS() throws NamingException, JMSException {

     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
     Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
     connection.start();


     Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

     // Getting the queue 'testQueue'
     Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQueue");


     MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);         

    // set an asynchronous message listener
    JMSReceiver asyncReceiver = new JMSReceiver();
    consumer.setMessageListener(asyncReceiver);

     connection.setExceptionListener(asyncReceiver);

}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    System.out.println("Received message : " +message);
}
```

}

Comment: did you try removing the `connection.close()` from your consumer?

Comment: Thanks for your time. please check my update

Comment: Since it is java program it should run within a jvm (java.exe).Possibilities are either run your consumer in a server like tomcat or run as main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Tim Bish said is correct. You either need to have a timer say for example receiver should listen for 1 hour- or make it available until program terminate. Either case you need to start your consumer program once:

Change your receiveJMS method as follows:

```
 public void receiveJMS() throws NamingException, JMSException {
try{
     ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
     Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
     connection.start(); // it's the start point


     Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

     // Getting the queue 'testQueue'
     Destination destination = session.createQueue("testQueue");


     MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);         

    // set an asynchronous message listener
   // JMSReceiver asyncReceiver = new JMSReceiver(); 
   //no need to create another object
    consumer.setMessageListener(this);

     connection.setExceptionListener(this);

     // connection.close(); once this is closed consumer no longer active

    Thread.sleep(60 *60 * 1000);             // receive messages for 1 hour
   }finally{
      connection.close();// after 1 hour close it
   }

}
```

The above program will listen upto 1 hour. If you want it as long as the program run, remove the `finally` block. But the recommended way is to close it somehow. since your application seems to be standalone ,you can check the [java runtime shutdown hook](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_addshutdownhook.htm), where you can specify how to release such resources while program terminates.

If your consumer is a web application you can close it in a `ServletContextlistner`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving the consumer application any time to actually receive a message, you create it, then you close it.  You either need to use a timed receive call to do an sync receive of the message from the Queue or you need to add some sort of wait in the main method such as a CountDownLatch etc to allow the async onMessage call to trigger shutdown once processing of the message is complete.

Comment: You are asking about a plain java application so a main method is required, for a service type scenario look at a container like Tomcat or some such, JMS defines nothing about containers or services.